# Vue onsen ui use component event

Tags: vue.js, onsen-ui

I'm trying to exploit this [onsen actionsheet](https://onsen.io/v2/api/vue/v-ons-action-sheet.html#event-posthide) and I'm trying to trigger event when actionsheet is hidden.

[image]

I tried

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#main',
    data() {
        return {
            actionSheetVisible: false
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$ons.posthide(function() {
            alert();
        });
    }
});
```

but seems I can't make it working. How can I add a listener for posthide event of the actionsheet?

Answer (score 0):

[Vue Event Handling Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) (@posthide="doSomething" or v-on:posthide="doSomething")

```
<v-ons-action-sheet @posthide="doSomething">
  ...
</v-ons-action-sheet>


new Vue({
  ...
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      alert('posthide!');
    }
  }
});
```